# How to show badges using pusher data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pusher, pusher-js

I am using pusher chatkit for my chatting app. Currently my app is able to chat with each individual, but my problem is if I (user1) am chatting with user2 and in between user3 text me from his account then how could I show badges that user3 sent me 4 messages.

Is there any solution or sample code to achieve this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the unread count for messages using the [unreadCount](https://pusher.com/docs/chatkit/reference/javascript#room-properties) room property. 
There is [a tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/unread-messages-react) which shows how to get the unread count and manage the cursors. 
The JS docs for Chatkit includes some code snippets for managing the unread count: 
https://pusher.com/docs/chatkit/reference/javascript.

For example, the following will log the unread count when a user joins a room, and will set the user's cursor each time a message is received.

```
currentUser.subscribeToRoomMultipart({
  roomId: this.currentRoom,
  messageLimit: 100,
  hooks: {
    //Message is received
    onMessage: message => {
      this.lastMessage = message.id;
      //set cursor
        currentUser.setReadCursor({
        roomId: this.currentRoom,
        position: this.lastMessage
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`Set cursor to message ${this.lastMessage}`)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(`Error setting cursor: ${err}`)
      })
    }
  },

}).then(room => {
  //log unread count
  console.log(`Unread count: ${room.unreadCount}`)
});
```